# Error with Python Matplotlib TypeError: Invalid input arguments to draw_text_image

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm a bit new to python so bear with me. I'm having an issue with plotting. So I have a data set of latitudes, longitudes, elevations and concentrations over time. I'm trying to plot concentration vs time for each elevation at each unique latitude and longitude. Below is the code i have written to try to accomplish this (i have imported all necessary modules in code before this, the following is just the snippet of code that is giving me problems)

```
lat=df['Lat']
lat=lat.unique()
from matplotlib import axes
for a in range(0,len(lat)): #for unique latitude
current_lat=lat[a]
mask=df[['Lat']].isin([current_lat]).all(axis=1)
df1=df.ix[mask]
lon=df1['Lon']
lon=lon.unique()
for b in range(0,len(lon)):
    current_lon=lon[b]
    mask=df1[['Lon']].isin([current_lon]).all(axis=1)
    df2=df1.ix[mask]
    df2=df2.sort('El',axis=0)
    elev=df2.El
    elev=elev.unique()
    plt.clf()
    #d['lat,lon']=(current_lat,current_lon)
    for c in range(0,len(elev)):
        current_elev=elev[c]
        mask=df2[['El']].isin([current_elev]).all(axis=1)
        df3=df2.ix[mask]
        df3=df3.sort()
        if len(df3)>1:
            x=df3.index
            x=list(x)
            y=list(df3.C)
            fig=plt.figure(a+b+1)
            ax=plt.subplot(111)
            fig.set_size_inches(22,12,forward=True)
            plt.plot(x,y,hold=True,label=current_elev)
            plt.legend() 
    del_x=float(x_coord_release)-float(current_lat)
    del_y=float(y_coord_release)-float(current_lon)
    dist=round(math.sqrt(del_x**2+del_y**2),3)
    textstr='Distance from release=\n%.2f\n'%(dist)
    props=dict(boxstyle='round',facecolor='wheat',alpha=0.5)
    #ax=plt.subplot(1,1,1)

    xlim=ax.get_xbound()
    ylim=ax.get_ybound()
    ax.text(xlim[1],ylim[1],textstr,bbox=props)
    ax.text(10,10,"Relative to Release Location",fontsize=9,color="black",bbox=dict(facecolor='wheat', alpha=0.5))   
    ax.set_title('Concentration vs Time based on Elevation at x={}, y={}'.format(int(round(float(current_lat),0)),int(round(float(current_lon),0))))
    figure_name='Concentration vs Time based on Elevation at x={}, y={}'.format(int(round(float(current_lat),0)),int(round(float(current_lon),0)))
    ax.set_xlabel('Time (min)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Concentration (mg/m$^3$)')
    fig.savefig(rdir+'\\'+figure_name+'.png',dpi=100) 
    #plt.show() 
    #plt.draw()
    #raw_input('enter')    
    plt.close()
```

The error message/Traceback I'm getting is the following:

```
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 C:\Users\bhall\Documents\Scripts\MESO_plot_v2.py in <module>()
 874         ax.set_xlabel('Time (min)')
 875         ax.set_ylabel('Concentration (mg/m$^3$)')
 --> 876         fig.savefig(rdir+'\\'+figure_name+'.png',dpi=100)
 877         #plt.show()
 878         #plt.draw()

 C:\Users\bhall\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-   packages\matplotlib\figure.pyc in savefig(self, *args, **kwargs)
 1474             self.set_frameon(frameon)
 1475 
 -> 1476         self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
 1477 
 1478         if frameon:

 C:\Users\bhall\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-  packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.pyc in print_figure(self, *args,   **kwargs)
 159 
 160     def print_figure(self, *args, **kwargs):
 --> 161         FigureCanvasAgg.print_figure(self, *args, **kwargs)
 162         self.draw()
 163 

 C:\Users\bhall\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.pyc in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, **kwargs)
2209                 orientation=orientation,
2210                 bbox_inches_restore=_bbox_inches_restore,
-> 2211                 **kwargs)
2212         finally:
2213             if bbox_inches and restore_bbox:

C:\Users\bhall\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.pyc in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
 519 
 520     def print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs):
 --> 521         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
 522         renderer = self.get_renderer()
 523         original_dpi = renderer.dpi

 C:\Users\bhall\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.pyc in draw(self)
 467 
 468         try:
 --> 469             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
 470         finally:
471             RendererAgg.lock.release()

C:\Users\bhall\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
 57     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
 58         before(artist, renderer)
 ---> 59         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
 60         after(artist, renderer)
 61 

 C:\Users\bhall\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.pyc in draw(self, renderer)
 1083         dsu.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
 1084         for zorder, a, func, args in dsu:
 -> 1085             func(*args)
 1086 
 1087         renderer.close_group('figure')

 C:\Users\bhall\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
 57     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
 58         before(artist, renderer)
 ---> 59         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
 60         after(artist, renderer)
 61 

 C:\Users\bhall\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.pyc in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
 2108 
 2109         for zorder, a in dsu:
 ->   2110             a.draw(renderer)
 2111 
 2112         renderer.close_group('axes')

 C:\Users\bhall\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
 57     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
 58         before(artist, renderer)
 ---> 59         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
 60         after(artist, renderer)
 61 

 C:\Users\bhall\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.pyc in draw(self, renderer)
 640                 renderer.draw_text(gc, x, y, clean_line,
 641                                    self._fontproperties, angle,
 --> 642                                    ismath=ismath, mtext=mtext)
 643 
 644         gc.restore()

 C:\Users\bhall\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.pyc in draw_text(self, gc, x, y, s, prop, angle, ismath, mtext)
 204         #print x, y, int(x), int(y), s
 205         self._renderer.draw_text_image(
 --> 206             font.get_image(), np.round(x - xd), np.round(y + yd) + 1, angle, gc)
 207 
 208     def get_text_width_height_descent(self, s, prop, ismath):

TypeError: Invalid input arguments to draw_text_image
```

It succesfully loops through several of the plots but keeps crashing on one plot and gives that error. I've tried just plotting that data manually and i have no issues so i'm at a loss as to what the problem/resolution is. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you reduce this to the _minimal_ amount of code required to reproduce the error?  The less working code you show in your question the more likely you are to get a good answer.

Comment: @tcaswell unfortunately i already have reduced it to the minimal amount of code i need to share to reproduce the error...the multiple for loops help to sort out the unique lat and long and then loop over all the elevations that occur for those lat and long coordinates